# Как определить координаты элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как определить координаты элемента относительно всего документа и относительно видимой части окна в javascript? После события `onscroll` координаты элемента относительно видимой части окна должны измениться. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: 1. [element.getBoundingClientRect](http://javascript.ru/ui/offset)
2. [scrollTop](http://javascript.ru/blog/Andrej-Paranichev/Izmereniya-okna-dokumenta-elementov#skroll-okna-brauzera)

Comment: Для случая получить абсолютные координаты [вот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759867/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-html-%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 12):

Координаты относительно видимой части документа — `.getBoundingClientRect()`. Этот метод также возвращает ширину и высоту элемента.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var c = this.getBoundingClientRect()
  alert('top:' + c.top + ' left: ' + c.left +'');
}
```

```css
button {
  margin: 500px 0 0;
}
span {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>scroll down</span>
  <button>getBoundingClientRect()</button>
<div>
```

Координаты относительно начала документа — значение `.scrollTop / .scrollLeft` + `.getBoundingClientRect().top / .getBoundingClientRect().left`

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var c = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
      scrolltop = document.body.scrollTop + c.top,
      scrollleft = document.body.scrollLeft + c.left;
  alert('top:' + scrolltop + ' left: ' + scrollleft + '');
}
```

```css
button {
  margin: 500px 0 0 500px;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>scroll down & left</span>
  <button>getBoundingClientRect() + scrollTop</button>
</div>
```

> Более подробно на [learn.javascript.ru/coordinates](https://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates)
>
> MDN: [.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop), [.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: Галочку поставить не смогу, зато вручаю награду. )

Answer (score 5):

Координаты относительно всего документа с jQuery:

```
$('#element').offset();
```

Возвращает left и top относительно документа. Относительно прокрутки(скролла) - как уже писали, лидер по лаконичности `getBoundingClientRect`