# Как вычислить координаты html элемента

Tags: javascript, html

Как вычислить (получить) позицию html елемента. `offsetTop` и `offsetLeft` даёт относительное значение (не всегда отчёт от точки `[x=0,y=0]` начала координат). Гугл даёт "недоделанный" вариант http://javascript.ru/ui/offset.

Не "*как динамический во время scroll определить текущее местоположение элемента по отношению к родителю*", а как получить абсолютные координаты относительно левого верхнего угла содержимого страницы.

Второй вопрос "*определить текущее местоположение элемента по отношению к родителю*" ещё раз повторяю, абсолютные координаты относительно левого верхнего угла содержимого страницы.

Нужно для "подвешивания" элементов к текущей верстке (что бы вывести на/возле определённого элемента подсказку, сообщение, рекламу и т.п.) например так:

```
      document.getElementById("act_holder").style.position= "absolute";
      document.getElementById("act_holder").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("act_holder").style.top = 
          (getOffset(document.getElementById("act_hlp")).top - 75 ) + "px";    
      document.getElementById("act_holder").innerHTML = "элемент занят";
```

при использовании `absolute` нужны координаты относительно левого верхнего угла.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70499/discussion-on-question-by-nick-n-a----html-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот код с javascript.ru собраный до кучи.

```
function getOffset(elem) {
        if (elem.getBoundingClientRect) {
        var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
        var body = document.body;
        var docElem = document.documentElement;
        var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
        var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;
        var clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;
        var clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;
        return { top: Math.round(box.top +  scrollTop - clientTop), left: Math.round(box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft) }      
        } else {
             var top=0, left=0
        while(elem) {
            top = top + parseFloat(elem.offsetTop);
            left = left + parseFloat(elem.offsetLeft);
            elem = elem.offsetParent ;
           }
           return {top: top, left: left};
           }
    }
```

Немного комментариев:
ф-ция getBoundingClientRect вызвала спор, [mozilla](http://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) цитата

> Возвращаемое значение getBoundingClientRect — это объект TextRectangle, содержащий свойства
>   только для чтения left, top, right и bottom, описывающие бокс с
>   границами в пиксельном измерении. Значения top и left даются
>   относительно верхнего левого угла порта просмотра.

т.е. уже с учётом скролла и отступов документа, которые приходится вычитать если нужны координаты относительно начала системы координат листа (левый верхний угол документа). Даная функция `getBoundingClientRect`  даст верный результат, если выполняется два условия: 1) позиция скроллинга ноль (на старте часто так), 2) если у документа (body) отступы не заданы, или заданы в ноль. Так как эти условия не всегда соблюдены - приходится использывать более сложные решения.

От себя добавлю, что если используется система отчёта `position=fixed` то `getBoundingClientRect` выдаст координаты которые подойдут к этой системе отчёта, но fixed редко используется, поскольку при *изменении позиции скрола* - позиция на экране *сохраняется* и елемент будет "плавать". А для absolute и static прийдётся делать пересчёт коодинат. Система relative - просто относительные координаты, в отдельных случаях её можно использовать.

Comment: Если есть более короткий вариант (браузеры не стоят на месте) буду рад. Цикл - не предлагать:)

Comment: Думаю, как минимум всю `else` часть можно выкинуть, так как `getBoundingClientRect` есть даже в IE8

Answer (score 1):

Кликни на любой элемент получишь данные
Объясни, какие ты еще хочешь получить координаты абсолютные???  Вполне вероятно, что пойму...
Смотреть лучше на весь экран

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var infomBlock = document.getElementById('infomBlock');
var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('blocks');

function getСoordinates(elem) {
  return coord = [
    'это абсолютное значени нижней границы элемента от окна просмотра - bottom ' + elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
    '<br/>это абсолютное значени верхней  границы элемента от окна просмотра - top ' + elem.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    '<br/> это абсолютное значени левой границы элемента от окна просмотра - left ' + elem.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    '<br/>right это абсолютное значени правой границы элемента от окна просмотра - ' + elem.getBoundingClientRect().right,
    '<br/>height - это абсолютное значени высоты элемента ' + elem.getBoundingClientRect().height,
    '<br/>width - это абсолютное значени ширины элемента ' + elem.getBoundingClientRect().width,
    '<br/>x - это абсолютное значени верхнего левого угла элемента по координате х' + elem.getBoundingClientRect().x,
    '<br/>y - это абсолютное значени верхнего левого угла элемента по координате y ' + elem.getBoundingClientRect().y,
  ];

  console.log(...coord)

}

for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  blocks[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    getСoordinates(this);
    infomBlock.innerHTML = coord;
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

#wrapper {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#infomBlock.blocks {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, .5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
}

.blocks {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px 20px;
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
}

.blocks:nth-child(even) {
  margin: 150px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="infomBlock" class="blocks"></div>
  <div class="blocks"></div>
  <div class="blocks"></div>
  <div class="blocks"></div>
  <div class="blocks"></div>
  <div class="blocks"></div>
  <div class="blocks"></div>
  <div class="blocks"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если используется jQuery - то всё просто:

```
$('#element').offset();//вернёт координаты в формате {top: float, left: float}
```

Будет работать всегда, кроме fixed-элементов. Это позиция от края документа - позиция внутри страницы.